# How to specify the return type based on function's argument?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.6, typing

Currently I've got this code:

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, data: Any):
        self.data = data
        # ...and much more than this

    def convert_value(self, value_type: Type['Value']) -> 'Value':
        return value_type(self.data)

class BooleanValue(Value):
    pass
```

The `convert_value` method converts an instance of `Value` into an instance of `value_type` passed as argument. For example:

```
value = Value(123)
new_value = value.convert_value(BooleanValue)
```

In this case `new_value` is of type `BooleanValue`. I don't think it's necessary to do like this (there should be a better way):

```
new_value: BooleanValue = value.convert_value(BooleanValue)
```

Currently PyCharm understands that I return a `Value` instance, but I'd like it to understand from typing that a `BooleanValue` is returned.

I tried to do it this way:

```
T = TypeVar('T', 'Value')

class Value:
    # Other methods
    def convert_value(self, value_type: Type[T]) -> T:
        return value_type(self.data)
```

but PyCharm claims that `value_type` is not callable.

Question: how to make PyCharm understand that the object returned from this method has type `value_type`?

Answer (score 1):

Your type hints are correct, it's a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24161) in PyCharm

Comment: Thanks @user2235698 !